# Where to insert slackline into ratchet?

Tags: gear, slacklining

Where to I insert the slackline in this picture? Does the slackline wrap around a cylinder of the ratchet or just hang? I can't get the line to be locked in place.

It'd be helpful if someone would paint over this.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The slackline goes through the center drum to hold it in place. Better than editing a picture, you can see how it works from [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T1bRc4vkiBM) at 0:49. Basically you have to provide a bit of tension, so that the line wraps around the center drum and then catches and winds on in a "doubled over" form as at 1:20ish in the video.

Comment: How did you find the video? I got stuck trying to find it.

Comment: I tried googling "Threading a ratchet strap", "How to use a ratchet strap", "How to setup slackline ratchet" and they all bring up multiple (almost identical) videos. Not sure what exact search @bob1 used, but I'm curious as to what you (@Germania) tried searching that didn't bring up a similar video?

Comment: "how to tie a slackline" site:youtube.com

Comment: I guess that doesn't make sense, because nothing is tied.

Comment: I used something along the lines of "how to use ratchet"